# Different Access levels for users by using PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a website for testing with logging page with different access levels for users, the site is connected with MySQL db which have 3 columns

> user | password | level(1/2)

code is filter out the particular entry from db but it didn't redirected to particular page. i tested with `echo` but at the `$count` it shows 0 . please help me to sort this out, I am going to use `mysqli` instead at the launching phase.

```
session_start();
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$conn = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
$db = mysql_select_db('udb',$conn);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM logins WHERE user ='".$username."' AND password = '".$password."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$conn);
echo $result;
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);


if ($count==1) {

    $_SESSION['login_user']=$username;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        if ($row['level'] == '2') {
            header("home2.php");
        } else {
            header("home1.php");
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: You are using the header function in the wrong way. Try this; `header("location: http://example.com/home2.php");`

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) [statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: [Don't limit passwords](http://jayblanchard.net/security_fail_passwords.html)  and [use the proper methods to hash passwords with PHP](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html).

Comment: Ugur & Jay thanks a lot.yes i already mentioned that i used mysql_* for testing :-) , at the launching i'm going to use mysqli_*

Answer (score 1):

Your `echo $result;` will prevent any further redirect down in the code. It is due to the fact that redirects are managed using headers... but since you output some data ... headers can not be managed.

Answer (score 1):

no need to give connection variable in `mysql_query()` and in header function u forgot to pass `location`

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM logins WHERE user ='".$username."' AND password = '".$password."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
//echo $result;
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);


if ($count==1) {

    $_SESSION['login_user']=$username;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
     {
        if ($row['level'] == '2') 
        {
            header("location:home2.php");
        } else {
            header("location:home1.php");
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `location` if you want your redirects to work.

```
if ($row['level'] == '2') {
    header("location: home2.php");
} else {
    header("location: home1.php");
}
```

[Your script is at risk for SQL Injection.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) [statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Finally, you should [use the proper methods to hash passwords with PHP](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html). The way that you're handling login is *extremely* insecure.

Comment: Thanks Jay , yep i only used mysql_* for this testing site . when it launch it will be mysqli_* :-)

Answer (score -1):

Place the user and password into back ticks (apostrophe marks on the left of key 1)